# Lossing value in array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

When i am trying to run this program all the values are just fine until p == "?" and there v[l].a, v[l].b are getting 0, and i am not sure why this is happening.
I know that i allocated more memory than necesary but i hope not there is the problem.

```
typedef struct line{
    int a;
    int b;
} line;


void checkIntersection (int c, line *v,int n){
    int result,k;
    result=0;
    for(k=0;k<=n;k++){
        if((v[k].a)==0)
            result=result;
        else if((c-v[k].b)%(v[k].a) == 0){
            result++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",result);
}

void dynamicLineIntersection(int n) {
    line *v;
    int c,d,j,l=-1;
    char p;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf(" %c",&p);
        v=(line*)malloc(n*sizeof(line));
        if(p == '+'){
            l++; 
            scanf("%d %d\n",&v[l].a,&v[l].b);
        }
        if(p == '-'){
            bool stop = false;
            scanf("%d%d\n", &c, &d);
            for(j=0;j<l && !stop;j++){
                if(c==v[j].a && d==v[j].b){
                    v[j].a=0;
                    stop=true;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d",v[l].a);
        if(p == '?'){
            scanf("%d\n", &c);
            checkIntersection(c,v,l);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d \n", &n);
    dynamicLineIntersection(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:
4
+ 1 0
+ 2 0
? 1
? 2
Output:
1
2
The ideea is how many of the lines (ax+b) intersect with a paralel Ox line ,y=c, in a point X (x MUST BE INTEGER). + means i have to add a line, - remove a line , ? i have to print how many lines intersect in a int x with y=c .

Answer (score 0):

Before you can worry about determining intersections, you must be able to read valid data first. You fail to check the return of a single `scanf` call, so you can have no confidence your code actually processes valid data. Your use of `scanf` is horribly fragile, prone to breakage by any additional characters the user may input. Using `scanf("%d%d\n", ...` does not cause the `'\n'` specified to be consumed, it is simply an incorrect use of `scanf`.

When you take User-Input, you must validate each and every input and handle any input error that occurs. You do this by, at minimum, checking the **return** for the input function you are using, and, if required, validate the input you receive is withing the necessary range you expect. You should further insure there are no characters left in your input buffer that will causer your next input to fail by clearing the input buffer as required.

You must validate ALL memory allocations just like you must validate ALL user input. (again, you do this by *checking the **return***) You allocate memory, but do not `free` it, and provide no method by which it can be freed once you return from `dynamicLineIntersection`. Either declare `dynamicLineIntersection` as type `line *` and return a pointer to `main()` or `free(v)` before the function returns.

Space your code properly. You code is almost impossible to read because you smash all characters together. This makes debugging and catching errors in your code difficult (especially for older eyes).

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* in `checkIntersection` by accessing values beyond the end of your array with

```
for(k=0;k<=n;k++)
```

Valid execution stops when undefined behavior is invoked and your code can do anything from appear to work correctly to SegFault. You only allocate `'n'` elements, so your loop limit must be `k < n`, not `k <= n`, that is one iteration too many.

If you are taking input from a user, **prompt** the user for the input. Don't leave the user staring at a blinking cursor wondering if your program hung up or is spinning away in an infinite loop.

If you are using `scanf`, then it is up to you to handle and remove all additional extraneous characters a user may input, **before** attempting your next input. A simple helper function can make this task much easier, e.g.

```
/* funciton to empty stdin between inputs */
void empty_stdin(void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Putting all those pieces together (and probably fixing several more errors that have currently slipped my mind), you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct line {
    int a;
    int b;
} line;

/* funciton to empty stdin between inputs */
void empty_stdin(void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

void checkIntersection (int c, line *v, int n) 
{
    int result, k;
    result = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].a == 0)
            result = result;
        else if ((c-v[k].b) % (v[k].a) == 0)
            result++;
    }

    printf ("result: %d\n", result);
}

/* must return a pointer to v or it can never be freed
 * or you must free before returning.
 */
line *dynamicLineIntersection (int n) 
{
    line *v = malloc (n * sizeof *v);
    int c, d, i, j, l = -1;
    char p;

    if (!v) {   /* validate ALL memory allocations */
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fputs ("input (+,-,?) val [val]: ", stdout);
        /* validate ALL user input! */
        if (scanf (" %c", &p) != 1) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (p == '+') {
            l++; 
            if (scanf ("%d %d", &v[l].a, &v[l].b) != 2) {   /* validate! */
                fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if (p == '-') {
            int stop = 0;
            if (scanf ("%d %d", &c, &d) != 2) {     /* validate! */
                fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            for (j=0; j<l && !stop; j++){
                if (c == v[j].a && d == v[j].b) {
                    v[j].a = 0;
                    stop = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (p == '?'){
            if (scanf ("%d", &c) != 1) {    /* validate! */
                fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            checkIntersection (c, v, l);
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty any characters remaining in stdin */
    }
    return v;
}

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    line *v = NULL;

    fputs ("enter number of lines: ", stdout);  /* prompt */
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {                /* validate! */
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    empty_stdin();

    if ((v = dynamicLineIntersection (n)))
        free (v);   /* free memory you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `bool` has been changed to a simple `int` for `stop`. There is nothing wrong with using `bool`, but it is just as easy to use an `int`. If you have a huge number of these type flags, then including `stdbool.h` and using `bool` can save a bit of memory, but for 1 flag -- it's hardly worth the header inclusion)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayintersect
enter number of lines: 4
input (+,-,?) val [val]: + 1 0
input (+,-,?) val [val]: + 2 0
input (+,-,?) val [val]: ? 1
result: 1
input (+,-,?) val [val]: ? 2
result: 1
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arrayintersect
==4621== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4621== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4621== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4621== Command: ./bin/arrayintersect
==4621==
enter number of lines: 4
input (+,-,?) val [val]: + 1 0
input (+,-,?) val [val]: + 2 0
input (+,-,?) val [val]: ? 1
result: 1
input (+,-,?) val [val]: ? 2
result: 1
==4621==
==4621== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4621==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4621==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==4621==
==4621== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4621==
==4621== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4621== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Well, that's a good lesson and and more info that i knew , i usally check if there memory is allocate well but my program break my 2 sec limit time (no error for memory allocated ) and i tried to limit the comparations and other things . 
I will try to remember all these and use in my future codes, but my first concern is time (values max 10^5) so if u can give an advice it would be great .

Comment: The only thing that jumps out is the use of 3-loops, 2 in `dynamicLineIntersection` and a 3rd in `checkIntersection`. Eliminating the function call can save a minimal amount of time, but the compiler is most likely already doing good optimization there. Are you compiling with full optimizations enabled? `-Ofast` or `-O3`? (the options is `Ohh3` not `Zero3`)

Comment: I don't know what optimizations are enabled because i upload the code and he runs tests, and for some tests(big numbers probably) i get timeout . And i can't imagine a possibility to solve my task without these 3 fors ( the most efficient way i could imagine)

Comment: What about moving the `checkIntersection` inside `dynamicLineIntersection` to eliminate the function call overhead? You can allso read once using `int rtn = scanf (" %c %d %d", &p, &c, &d); if (rtn == 3) { /* then check +/- val val */ } else if (rtn == 2) { /* handled ? val */ } else { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: I will try when i get home , i will let u know the result.

Comment: i tried to move the function inside the dynamicLineIntersection, but i can't read like u said because my input is based on char p.
Moving the function still gives me timeout, any other ideas ?